# Explain query - MySQL not using index from table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm trying to learn the `explain` statement in MySQL but ran into a wall.

For my experiment, I created two tables (each having 10 rows) and ran `explain` over a simple join. Naturally, no indexes were used and 10*10 = 100 rows were scanned (I've added the output in images because the very long output of EXPLAIN was being wrapped on itself. The code is also in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1sepb6u0)):

[image: Bad table design]

I then added primary keys and indexes and reissued the `explain` command:

[image]

But as you can see, the users table is still being fully scanned by MySQL, as if there was no primary key. What is going wrong?

Comment: if the whole `users` table was not scanned it would not have joined all the scanned users to `accounts` , only one where and one ref clause limiting the accounts. - use more records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking about `EXPLAIN`, `INDEXing`, and optimizing particular `SELECTs`.

For this:

```
select  u.name
    from  users as u
    join  accounts as a on u.id = a.user_id
    where  a.amount > 1000;
```

the optimizer will pick between `users` and `accounts` for which table to look at first.  Then it will repeatedly reach into the other table.

1. Since you say `a.amount > ...` but nothing about `u`, the optimizer is very likely to pick `a` first.
2. If `a.amount > 1000` is selective enough (less than, say, 20% of the rows) *and* there is `INDEX(amount)`, it will use that index.  Else it will do a table scan of `a`.
3. To reach into `u`, it needs some index starting with `id`.  Keep in mind that a `PRIMARY KEY` *is* an index.

This, and many more basics, are covered in [my index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

See also [myxlpain](http://www.myxplain.net/) for a discussion of `EXPLAIN`.

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` is also somewhat cryptic, but it does have more details than a regular `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Basically, your tables are too small.  You cannot get reasonable performance indications on such small data -- the query only needs to load two data pages into memory for the query.  A nested loop join requires 100 comparisons.  By comparison, loading indexes and doing the binary search is probably about the same amount of effort, if not more.

If you want to get a feel for `explain`, then use tables with a few tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: Thanks! So you mean to say I was on the right track? :D

Answer (score 1):

well, 
As your main filter has '>' comparison operator, it does full table scan Because it may or may not return all rows.

as you join the 'accounts' table  with 'user_id' column, it shows the 'user_id' index in Possible Keys, but it doesn't use it, because of the FULL TABLE SCAN process.

Comment: I don't think the comparison operator always implies a full table scan. That would bring almost all databases to their knees. And by the way, I tested without the `where` condition and the result is still the same.

Comment: @dotslash, yes, it will go with a table scan, if you use this  comparison operator, because you don't have index on <amount> column.